# Dynamically linking a simple binary

Tags: c, linker

I want to write my own ld.so and I want to do it step by step. I could not find any "guide" on how to code my ld.so, so I want to do it myself. I thought I would first try loading a simple binary in memory, like the one below; then call it. It's extremely simple, and it's already not working.

The binary is:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov edi, 123
    mov eax, 60
    syscall
```

calling exit(123):

```
$ nasm -f elf64 bin.asm && ld bin.o && ./a.out; echo $?
$ 123
```

The loader:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_t sz = ftell(fp) + 1;
    rewind(fp);

    char *contents = malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
    size_t pagesize = getpagesize();
    void *base_addr = (void*) (pagesize * (1 << 20));

    char *region = mmap(
            base_addr,
            pagesize,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
            MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE,
            0, 0
            );
    if (region == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1, nread = 0; nread != sz * sizeof(char) && i > 0; nread += i) {
        i = fread(contents, sizeof(char), sz, fp);
    }
    contents[sz - 1] = 0;
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error reading file %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(region, contents, sz);
    if (mprotect(region, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mprotect failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return ((int (*)()) base_addr)();
```

What I think will happen: my_linker -> binary in memory -> call `mov edi, 123`, return 123.

What happens: "SIGSEGV at address 0x0"

I'm running this on Linux x86_64.

---

EDIT: in response to @Ctx. `memcpy` instead of `strncpy`.

I should have stated it cleared. I'm running `nasm -f elf...` to show that it does what it is expected. As a program argument, `nasm -f bin -o prog.bin ...` the binary file.

Comment: @Ctx no, it can't. `mov eax, 60` in 64 bit sets the upper part of rax to 0

Comment: Yes, that's correct, never ran across that fact. Interesting. It is a bit inconsistent, because when using %ax it's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main issues:

**Inappropriate use of `strncpy()`**

Here, you use `strncpy()` to copy the binary code into your `mmap()`ped page:

```
strncpy(region, contents, sz);
```

But `strncpy()` stops copying at the first zero byte, and there is probably quite early one in the binary. You have to use `memcpy()` for this task!

Second issue:

**The ELF format**

You assume, that the code starts at the beginning of your binary. But here

```
$ nasm -f elf64 bin.asm && ld bin.asm && ./a.out; echo $?
```

you are linking it to an ELF format binary. So it starts with ELF headers, not with the code. There are essentially two possibilities: Either calculate the offset from the ELF headers, or use `objcopy` to extract the pure code from the binary:

```
objcopy -O binary -j text a.out bin
```

Edit: You tried to use

nasm -f bin -o prog.bin bin.asm

but this produces **16-bit code** by default. You have to explicitly state

```
bits 64
```

in your assembler source file to get 64-bit code.

**Why use fread()/memcpy()**

There is not much point to use `fread()` into a buffer and `memcpy()` afterwards, you could just directly `mmap()` the binary into the memory without reading it.

```
char *region = mmap(
        base_addr,
        sz,
        PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED,
        fileno(fp), 0
        );
```

Comment: Good call on `memcpy`. See my edit. I use the binary file; the elf64 one is just to show (myself) it works as expected (side note: the mmap without memcpy does not fix the issue)

Comment: @bicup I have edited the answer and believe to have found the problem

Comment: That was subtle. Great catch Ctx. Next: read a simple ELF, read dependencies, read .text segment and see what comes out. If you have any suggestion or guidance, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for spotting this!

Comment: @bicup Well, you should start with trying to execute a statically linked ELF binary. For this, you basically have to iterate through the ELF _Program Headers_ (the section headers are not relevant in this step) and map the parts of the binary to the memory addresses specified (otherwise it would work only with position independent code). Then you jump to the address specified in the "program entry point" ELF header field.

Comment: Good advice. What happens if there is an overlap between my linker and the addresses of the ELF? Do I need to make my linker a library like ld.so or is there another way (that does not involve remapping my whole process all the time)?

Comment: @bicup The dynamic linker is usually loaded somewhere in the address range where also the libraries go (i.e. with 64-bit somewhere around 0x7f8.........). It should be possible for your program to be loaded somewhere in that vincity by giving the linker appropriate commands or linker scripts. Then it should not collide with regularly linked programs.